# How many ways can 7 identical gifts be distributed among 10 children if no child is allowed to get more than 1 gift/ if children are allowed to get…

Tags: combinatorics

> 1. How many ways can 7 identical gifts be distributed among 10 children if no child is allowed to get more than 1 gift?
> 2. How many ways can 7 identical gifts be distributed among 10 children if children are allowed to get more
>    than 1 gift?

For problem 1, I was able to find an answer, but I am unsure if it is correct. The way I did this was:

Number of ways of dividing n identical gifts to r children is:

$n+r-1$ choose $r-1$, where $n=7$ and $r=3$, then $\binom{16}{9}$or

$\frac{16!}{{7!}\times{9!}}$ ways.

For problem 2, I am unsure of where to start?

Comment: For $1$, you just need to pick the seven children who will get a gift.  The calculation you did is more appropriate for $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1, you just choose the seven children who will get gifts, so $10\choose 7$ ways

Your answer to 1 is the correct approach for 2